# How to dynamically position and scale iframe on browser zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

**The Problem**

A user can choose to create an iframe by pasting in their iframe code or url. When the window re-sizes the iframe needs to stay positioned in the middle and bottom of the page. I have gotten the iframe to stay in the middle and the bottom of the page for the most part. But when the window re-sizes (a user zooms in(150% etc) or out(50% etc)) the iframe itself gets larger when a user zooms in and smaller when a user zooms out. Since I can't target the contents within the iframe, I have been trying to figure out a way of applying a scale to the iframe so that it would appear to stay the same size and at the same position. I am having trouble dynamically figuring out the scale of an iframe when the window re-sizes.

**The Javascript**

**load event**

```
                jQuery('#iframe_wrapper iframe').attr('id','iframe');
                jQuery( "#iframe" ).load(function() {
                    jQuery('#adhesion_iframe').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(1)');
                });
```

**position**

```
ratio = $('#iframe').width() / ($('#iframe').height() + ($('#close_btn')close.length>0 ? 0 : 20));


 if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
                        var width = window.innerWidth / 1.5 / 1.5;
                        $('#iframe_wrapper').css({
                            width: width + "px",
                            height: window.innerWidth / ratio / 1.5 + "px",
                            left: parseInt((window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth / 2) - (width / 2)) + "px",
                            top: parseInt(window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset - window.innerWidth / ratio / 1.5 / 1.5) + "px"
                        });
```

**iframe**

```
if($('#iframe').length >0 ){

                    jQuery.fn.center = function(){
                        this.css("position","absolute");
                        this.css("top","60%");
                        this.css("left","50%");
                        this.css("margin-top","-"+(this.height()/2)+"px");
                        this.css("margin-left","-"+(this.width()/2)+"px");
                        return this;}

                    $('#iframe').center();

                $('iframe').css({
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scale('+(document.body.offsetWidth * scale / initial_width )
                });

                }
```

When the page loads the initial scale would be set to 1. I was thinking of doing something like this to dynamically change the scale on window re-size  **'-webkit-transform': 'scale('+(document.body.offsetWidth * scale / initial_width)**. So if the zoom level goes to 150% then the scale would be something like 0.something and if the zoom level goes to 50% then the scale may be 2.something etc..... Sure I can hard code the scale but that would only work on certain iframe sizes (the iframe width and height is dynamically set by the user). So it may work on an iframe that is 300 by 50 but not on one that is 600 by 100 etc.

Comment: Zoom and resize are two different things. Please edit and restrict your question to one or the other unless both apply.

Comment: just on zoom for this particular case.. the resize is for mobile devices @isherwood

Answer (score -1):

I think you are overdoing it. Just set the size of the iframe to pixel values with css:

```
iframe {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px; 
}
```

Comment: I can't do that @Max because the size of the iframe will be different almost every time since the user is setting the dimensions themselves. So before the iframe gets inserted into the dom the width and height are set by the user. I am getting the width and height with javascript and trying to perform some calculations on that.